# How to set count to zero for missing keys in D3 nest()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am grouping data from a .csv file using d3.js. I am trying to use `d3.nest()` to get a count of the records by Year and then by Status.

My `test.csv` contains

```
Year,Project,Status
2018,Project 1,InProgress
2018,Project 2,InProgress
2018,Project 3,InProgress
2017,Project 4,InProgress
2017,Project 5,Completed
2017,Project 6,InProgress
2016,Project 7,Completed
```

And my code looks like this:

```js
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benubah/rconsortium_projects/master/test.csv")
  .then(function(data) {
    var stat = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.Year  })
      .key(function(d) { return d.Status }) 
      .rollup(function(v) { return  v.length })
      .entries(data);
      
    console.log(stat);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
```

I expect the output of (since there are no Completed projects in 2018, set Completed key to 0):

```
[Object {
   key: "2018",
   values: [Object {
      key: "InProgress",
      value: 3
}, Object {
      key: "Completed",
      value: 0
}]
},
 Object {
   key: "2017",
   values: [Object {
      key: "InProgress",
      value: 2
}, Object {
      key: "Completed",
      value: 1
}]
},
Object {
   key: "2016",
   values: [Object {
      key: "InProgress",
      value: 0
}, Object {
      key: "Completed",
      value: 1
}]
}]
```

But the actual output I get is:

```
[Object {
   key: "2018",
   values: [Object {
      key: "InProgress",
      value: 3
}]
},
 Object {
   key: "2017",
   values: [Object {
      key: "InProgress",
      value: 2
}, Object {
      key: "Completed",
      value: 1
}]
},
Object {
   key: "2016",
   values: [Object {
      key: "Completed",
      value: 1
}]
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that those year/status combinations, which would have to produce the entries with `values: 0`, do not exist in the source data. d3 only iterates the *existing* combinations...

So you would have to fill the gaps with your own code. It can be done in many ways. One is to chain a `.map` which adds the missing `values` entry where necessary:

```js
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benubah/rconsortium_projects/master/test.csv")
  .then(function(data) {
    var stat = d3.nest()
      .key(d => d.Year)
      .key(d => d.Status) 
      .rollup(v => v.length)
      .entries(data)
      .map(function (obj) {
           if (obj.values.length === 1) {
               if (obj.values[0].key == "Completed") {
                   obj.values.unshift({ key: "InProgress", values: 0 });
               } else {
                   obj.values.push({ key: "Completed", values: 0 });
               }
           }
           return obj;
      });
      
    console.log(stat);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! Your answer is straight to the solution.